# Putting each word into an <a> tag and highlighting the begin to end of each word

Tags: javascript, html, css

Each word has a begin, end, and returns the word too as text. I need to put each word into an `<a>` tag and also highlight each word.

```
complexWordIdentification(text, words) {
  // list of "complex words"
  const complexWords = words;
  // array will be populated with results.
  const results = [];
  // loop through each complex word and see if it occurs in the text
  let match, regexp;

  for (let i = 0; i < complexWords.length; i++) {
    // the complex word we are checking in this iteration
    const complexWord = complexWords[i];
    // the complex word we are checking in this iteration
    regexp = new RegExp(complexWord, 'g');

    while ((match = regexp.exec(text)) !== null) {
      // the results object
      const result = {
        begin: (regexp.lastIndex - complexWords[i].length),
        end: regexp.lastIndex,
        text: complexWord
      };
      // add the object to the results array
      const index = results.length;
      results[index] = result;
      console.log(results[index]);
    }
  }
  // return the results array when done
  return results;
}
```

The results to this function would be this:

```
{begin: 6, end: 11, text: "Lorem"}
{begin: 112, end: 117, text: "Lorem"}
{begin: 218, end: 223, text: "Lorem"}
```

I have a function which I can put words into an `<a>` tag and highlight them this is the function:

```
highlightSelection() {
  this.complexWordIdentification(this.postIWant, this.theHardWords);
  const userSelection = window.getSelection();
  if (userSelection.toString() === null) {
    return;
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < userSelection.rangeCount; i++) {
      this.highlightRange(userSelection.getRangeAt(i));
      this.word = userSelection.toString();
    }
  }
}

guidGenerator() {
  const S4 = () => {
    return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
  };
  return (S4() + S4() + '-' + S4() + '-' + S4() + '-' + S4() + '-' + S4() + S4() + S4());
}

highlightRange(range) {
  const newNode = document.createElement('a');
  newNode.id = this.guidGenerator();
  newNode.className = 'annotation_class';
  newNode.setAttribute(
      'style',
      'background-color: yellow; display: inline;'
    ),
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
  this.viewAnnotation(newNode.id);
}
```

That function above can highlight text etc and do what I want to do but that would be manual, I need to do it when I run the `complexWordIdentification` function to put each word into an `<a>` tag and highlight them.

Anyone got any advice on how to get around this, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't understand the question completely, but why not just `.replace()` every word with `<a class="highlighted">${word}</a>`?

Comment: @Shilly The highlighting function I showed highlights each word manually, but I'm trying to highlight every word in the document as soon as the first function has run. Would you be able to expand on the `.replace()`? How or where could I implement this, thanks!

Comment: So your document does not contain any links that the keywords could be found in to begin with? (Because putting a link into something that was already a link, would obviously be invalid.)

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean? In the function `complexWordIdentification` it contains all the complexWords from the database. It finds them all in the document as stated and it returns `{begin: 6, end: 11, text: "Lorem"}` of each word. I just need to instead of saying begin:6 etc I need to actually do something with it which is put it into an `<a>` and style it.

Comment: I mean that if you have content that could contain something like `foo <a href="...">bar baz</a> boink` already to begin with, and your script now tried to wrap the searched word `bar` in an additional link, it would be creating highly nonsensical output to begin with. Just saying that you need to keep that case in mind, if at all applicable.

Comment: @CBroe oh okay thanks, but that's not the case here, its just word on the screen which needs to be put into an `<a>` then styled. Need to get this to work asap but I cant seem to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing some of the requirements or so, but I would just go for basic `String.replace()` if I have no need for a list of all word indexes.

```js
const guid = () => {
  const S4 = () => {
    return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
  };
  return (S4() + S4() + '-' + S4() + '-' + S4() + '-' + S4() + '-' + S4() + S4() + S4());
};
const words = [
  "Lorem",
  "ipsum",
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "baz"
];
const highlight = ( node, words ) => {
  const text = node.innerHTML;
  const highlighted_text = words.reduce(( text, word ) => {
    return text.replace( new RegExp( word, 'g' ), `<a id="${guid()}" class="highlighted">${word}</a>` );
  }, text );
  node.innerHTML = highlighted_text;
};

highlight( document.querySelector( '#text_snippet' ), words );
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="text_snippet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri posse veniam eu. Adhuc appareat argumentum has cu. Vim cu tale moderatius. Eos cu nostrud vocibus offendit.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Shilly, but unfortunately I have not been able to get this to work.

Comment: I have tried this:  `highlightText = (node, words) => {
    const fileText = node;
    const highlighted_text = words.reduce(( fileText, word ) => {
      return fileText.replace( new RegExp( word, 'g' ), ` `<a id="${this.guidGenerator()}"class="highlighted">${word}</a>` );
    }, fileText );
    node = highlighted_text;
    console.log('node: ', node);
  }` `But the text does not get highlighted, even though the CSS class for it highlights it. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: On the line words.reduce that you have on the `.reduce(( text, word) => {` the text seems to say that its shadowed.

Comment: As you can see from the snippet, it works in the way I wrote it. Have you added that actually styling to your css? Have you tried replacing the class by inline styles? Does the browser you're using support all the ES6 features used?

Comment: Have you checked that `this.guidGenerator()` returns a valid id?

Comment: Yes, all those steps have been taken. I seem to get this blob of text when I console.log it: <a id="0b3b5c3c-ab04-48ad-116b-0ecb407216cc" class="highlighted">Hello</a> <a id="06682493-f3c4-94f3-a2be-60c635af085c" class="highlighted">Lorem</a> ipsum <a id="415968de-fdc0-4c34-4101-dc0c4fb66c4c" class="highlighted">dolor</a>

Comment: Which seems to be good stuff, but its a blob in the console.log its not acctually applying it though to the text on the screen.

Comment: That seems about right. But you don't see those words in blue? What does the inspector say the bgcolor of the a tags are? Maybe some other class is overwriting the styling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176064/discussion-between-andrew-and-shilly).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked to solve the issue I had.

With this, by having the words, I could put it into an `<a>` automatically and highlight it.

```
getWords(words) {
    this.highlight(words);
}

highlight = (words) => {
    const high = document.getElementById('scrollable');
    const paragraph = high.innerHTML.split(' ');
    const res = [];

    paragraph.map(word => {
      let t = word;
      if (words.indexOf(word) > -1) {
        t = '<a class="clickable" style="background-color: yellow;">' + word + '</a>';
      }
      res.push(t);
    });
    high.innerHTML = res.join(' ');
}
```